# How can I completely remove a list item and its content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i can´t remove li and html content, my html looks like:

```
<li>
    <a href="#dialog-form-image" rel="modal:open">
      <img src="http://www.miapp.cl/walmart/admincontenidoatg/wp-content/themes/admincontent/images/imagen_wf.jpg" name="img_164" id="flexslider">
    </a>
</li>
```

Remove action depend click a button with name of image.

```
    $("#btn-url-delete").live('click',function(){
        var id_img = $(this).attr("name");
        $('img[name="'+id_img+'"]').prev().prev().remove();
        $(this).remove();

    });
```

Comment: What ancient version of jQuery are you running that it supports `live`?

Comment: I would first change `live` to `on` same thing. DOn't think that will solve your problem though. Not sure was `btn-url-delete` is since you didn't post the html for that.

Comment: jQuery v1.7 i can´t change

Comment: What is `"#btn-url-delete"`? How does it correspond to that li?

Comment: with live no problem, this problem is select li element and delete

Comment: `.prev().prev()` doesn't travel to parents just siblings so you are selecting nothing since the `img` has no siblings... use `parent() or parents()`instead

Comment: `.llive()` is not a problem with the version of jQuery that supports it. Even if it is still deprecated, it will work. Yes it will bite them in the rear when they need to upgrade to the latest and greatest, but for now it is fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is `prev()` is siblings, not the parent. You need to select the parents to get to the li.

```
$('img[name="'+id_img+'"]').parent().parent().remove();
```

or

```
$('img[name="'+id_img+'"]').closest("li").remove();
```

Comment: Or `$('img[name="'+id_img+'"]').parents("li").remove();` :)